# Programmatically delete SharePoint file that is locked by another user

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, databricks

I want to delete a SharePoint file programmatically within a Databricks Notebook when it is opened (locked) by another user.
This is the code i have now:

```
    `ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(credentials)

file_url = "...."

target_file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(file_url) #SP.File object

executed_target_file = target_file.get().execute_query()
executed_target_file.delete_object()
ctx.execute_query()`
```

but because the file is opened by another user, i got the 423 Client Error: Locked for url: ([https://http.dev/423#:~:text=The%20423%20Locked%20status%20code,timer%20may%20expire%2C%20if%20applicable.](https://http.dev/423#:%7E:text=The%20423%20Locked%20status%20code,timer%20may%20expire%2C%20if%20applicable.))

I tried adding this part to the code, to first check if the file is checked out:

```
`# Check if the file is checked out
 if executed_target_file.properties.get('CheckOutType') != 0:
         # Check in the file
          target_file.checkin(comment="File check- 
 in").execute_query()
          ctx.execute_query()`
```

and after this delete it. But this still gives me the error.
Does anyone know how to programmatically delete a sharepoint file that is locked by another user?